# Oracle Constraint and null values

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

On an Oracle DB, if I have a Nullable column and a check constraint on the same column restricting the values to, say, 'ABC' or 'DEF', can I insert a row with a null value in that column (given that null is not one of the constraint values)?

Comment: Yes, Oracle will enforce all restrictions that are enabled. Can you share the constraint code so the question can be answered?

Comment: why do you ask? Try it out! http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read up on check (and other) constraints in the [Oracle Concepts manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datainte.htm#CNCPT33337).

In your case, yes you can insert a row with a null value because the check constraint (e.g. `mycolumn in ('ABC', 'DEF')` becomes effectively `NULL in ('ABC', 'DEF')` when mycolumn is null.  This Boolean expression will itself evaluate to null, just as `null = 'ABC'` does, because null is "unknown".  And check constraints are only violated if they evaluate to `false`. Hence your constraint allows you to insert 'ABC', 'DEF' or null into the column.

Answer (score 2):

> can I insert a row with a null value in that column

Yes you can since you have defined your column as nullable. If you supply a non-null value to the column then the supplied value must match with the values defined in `CHECK` constraint.

[See a live demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a656/1)